# CoreData relationships not merging from one MOC to another

Tags: ios, core-data, merge, relationship, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've been banging my head against the wall with this bug. Basically relationships aren't being merged from one context to another correctly.

Let's say I have two entity types in my model, Student and Teacher. A student can only have one teacher and a teacher can obviously have many students. I set this up correctly in my xcdatamodel class.

Because I'm syncing these entities from the server I have 2 Managed Object Contexts - one called `uiContext` which has it its concurrency type set to `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and another called `backgroundContext` with its concurrency type set to `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

I've also set up a nested structure using `[self.uiContext setParentContext:self.backgroundContext];`

So this is what I'm doing:

1) Fetch Teachers from the server

2) Create managed objects for them in `backgroundContext`

3) Call `save`  on `backgroundContext`

4) I listen for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, and execute the following code:

> ```
> [self.uiContext performBlock:^(void) {
>    [self.uiContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notif];
> }];
> ```

So far this works just fine. My uiContext gets the Teacher managed objects and my UI updates accordingly.

It breaks down though when I do the following:

5) Fetch the student data from the server

6) Create managed objects for them in the `backgroundContext` and **set the relationship from student to the appropriate teacher.**

7) Call `save`  on `backgroundContext`

8) Since I'm listening for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification this save should get merged into the `uiContext`

However, here's where I start experiencing issues. Even though the student objects are merged into the `uiContext` correctly, the relationship from teacher to student is not set. The relationship from student to teacher is correctly set but not the other way around. Specifically, `[someTeacherObject.students count] == 0` but `someStudentObject.teacher != nil`

The relationships are set correctly in both the `backgroundContext` and the persistent store (verified). Just not in the `uiContext`.

Any ideas what could be going on? Any idea how to better debug this?

Comment: In your data model, is the student entity's `teacher` relationship the inverse of the teacher entity's `students` relationship?

Comment: Yes that is set correctly. And I believe it must be because the data is setup correctly in the backgroundContext and in the persistant store.

Comment: If that's the case then it should be impossible to have `[someTeacherObject.students count] == 0` and `someStudentObject.teacher != nil`-- unless `someStudentObject.teacher` is actually pointing to a different teacher object than the `someTeacherObject` you're checking. As inverse relationships, setting the one to non-nil would force the other to have a count > 0. Are you sure you're comparing the same instances?

Comment: Ok did some more digging and you are correct, it seems like they are different teacher objects. I believe this is because the objectIds are different if I log `someTeacherObject.objectId` vs `someStudentObject.teacher.objectId`

Comment: If I have a teacher object in my backgroundContext and merge it into my uiContext, it should have the same objectId correct?

Comment: @aloo Did you solve the problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, once you have a parentContext set for your background context, you no longer need to listen out for changes and merge them manually. You do, however, need to perform an extra `saveContext:` on your main context to save the changes to the store.

See the 'Parent/Child Contexts' section of this [article on multi-context Core Data](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) for more information.

*Edit*

Taken from that article, the code would look something like:

```
[backgroundContext performBlock:^{
// do something that takes some time asynchronously using the bg context

   // push to parent
   NSError *error;
   if (![backgroundContext save:&error])
   {
       // handle error
   }

   // save parent to disk asynchronously
   [mainMOC performBlock:^{
        NSError *error;
        if (![mainMOC save:&error])
        {
           // handle error
        }
    }];
}];
```

Comment: I actually have it the other way around. My backgroundContext is the parent of my uiContext (see my code snippet in the question).

Comment: So I do need to merge changes made to my backgroundContext into my uiContext if I want to make changes to my backgroundContext